# Xquery, Javascript & HTML

Tags: html, jquery, xml, xquery

I need to do actions when pressing the checkbox with Javascript. To practice, I used this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <td>Consulta Medica</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" id="input695" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" id="695" autocomplete="off"> 
            </td>
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#695').change(function () {
                extraer = $('#input695').val();
                console.log(extraer)
            });
        });

    </script>
</html>
```

Using it in an HTML file works, but the point is that I intend to use it in an .xqy file and I can't. Does anyone know why? The error says:

> Static error near {...n () { $('#695'} on line 59 at column 17 of
> XPST0003  expected "", found "(" javax.xml.xquery.XQException:
> expected "", found "("  at
> com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.newXQException(SaxonXQConnection.java:201)
> at
> com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:113)
> at
> com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:97)
> at xquery.AppXQuery.execute(AppXQuery.java:36)  at
> xquery.AppXQuery.main(AppXQuery.java:19) Caused by:
> net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: expected "", found "("   at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:311)    at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:268)    at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.grumble(XPathParser.java:255)    at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.expect(XPathParser.java:241)     at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseVariableReference(XPathParser.java:2407)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:2204)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:2101)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:2020)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1982)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1996)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1849)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:752)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression(XPathParser.java:657)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4712)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.readElementContent(XQueryParser.java:4672)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseDirectElementConstructor(XQueryParser.java:4377)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parsePseudoXML(XQueryParser.java:4085)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseConstructor(XQueryParser.java:3369)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseBasicStep(XPathParser.java:2344)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseStepExpression(XPathParser.java:2101)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseRelativePath(XPathParser.java:2020)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parsePathExpression(XPathParser.java:1982)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseSimpleMappingExpression(XPathParser.java:1996)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseUnaryExpression(XPathParser.java:1849)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExprSingle(XPathParser.java:752)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.expr.parser.XPathParser.parseExpression(XPathParser.java:657)
> at net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.parseQuery(XQueryParser.java:374)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.XQueryParser.makeXQueryExpression(XQueryParser.java:171)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:568)
> at
> net.sf.saxon.query.StaticQueryContext.compileQuery(StaticQueryContext.java:630)
> at
> com.saxonica.xqj.SaxonXQConnection.prepareExpression(SaxonXQConnection.java:108)
> ... 3 more Cannot invoke "javax.xml.xquery.XQResultSequence.next()"
> because "result" is null

The link 59 starts in `$(document).ready(function () {`

Please help me :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CDATA section to put the Javascript code into the XQuery, to prevent the `{}` from being seen as delimiters of enclosed expressions:

```
    <script>
<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#695').change(function () {
                extraer = $('#input695').val();
                console.log(extraer)
            });
        });

    ]]></script>
```

Comment: Hello again, I tried it and it no longer generates that error. The problem now is that the page is empty.